# Python Django from does not work after refactoring

Tags: python, django

I have been working through the Tango With Django tutorial.  However, I noticed that some of the examples did not adhere to what people consider Django best practices, so I went back to do a little refactoring.  Here is how I first wrote a template for a form that allows a user to add a web page to a category.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% extends 'rango/base.html' %}
  {% block title %}Add a Page{% endblock %}

  {% block body_block %}
    <h1>Add a Page</h1>

    <form id="page_form" method="post" action="/rango/category/{{ category_name }}/add_page/">

      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field }}
      {% endfor %}

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page"></input>

    </form>

  {%endblock%}
</html>
```

I then refactored the template like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% extends 'rango/base.html' %}
  {% block title %}Add a Page{% endblock %}

  {% block body_block %}
    <h1>Add a Page</h1>

    <form id="page_form" method="post" action="{% url 'add_page' category_name %}"></form>

      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field }}
      {% endfor %}

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page"></input>

    </form>

  {%endblock%}
</html>
```

However, now when I click the submit button, nothing happens.  Here is the url pattern that I use:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page')
```

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def add_page(request, category_name_url):
  category_name = remove_underscores(category_name_url)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PageForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
      page = form.save(commit=False)

      try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
        page.category = cat
      except Category.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', {})

      page.views = 0

      page.save()

      return category(request, category_name_url)
    else:
      print form.errors
  else:
    form = PageForm()

  return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html',
    {'category_name_url': category_name_url,
     'category_name': category_name,
     'form': form})
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
  url(r'^about$', views.about, name='about'),
  url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
  url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
  url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
  url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
  url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
  url(r'^restricted/$', views.restricted, name='restricted'),
  url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
)
```

UPDATE:

I print out the result of {% url 'add_page' category_name %} and got /rango/category/Ruby/add_page/, which is the correct result.  Looks like the url tag is resolving to the correct path.  Still not sure why it is not working.

Comment: New `add_page` url doesn't seem to have the `/rango` part from the first block of codes. Does it?

Comment: Not sure.  Let me check and update the question.

Comment: Nothing happens? There is no error page (`Debug=True`) in your browser, and there are no errors in the console output where you are running the Django webserver?

Comment: I don't know what `remove_underscores` is from, but are you sure `category_name` is what you think it is? From your description, it sounds like you might be hitting that `Category.DoesNotExist` except block and just getting the blank form spit back at you.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see any error page in the browser or the console output, which is frustrating.  I'll take a look at `category_name`.

Comment: I put this code in the view: `category name url {{ category_name_url }} category name {{ category_name }}`.  I got back: `category name url Ruby category name Ruby`, which makes sense.  Is there anyway to print  out the result of `{% url 'add_page' category_name %}`?

Answer (score 0):

OMG!  I feel so lame!  This line was the issue:

```
<form id="page_form" method="post" action="{% url 'add_page' category_name %}"></form>
```

The fields and submit button were not enclosed in the form!  Ugh!

Comment: This line `return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', {})` can also be problematic.

Comment: What is the recommended syntax?

Comment: Instead `{}` you can pass `{'category_name_url': category_name_url,
     'category_name': category_name}`